# List of Array of objects to map in java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a class Person with constructor

```
Person(Fruit... favoriteFruits) {}
```

And 3 objects (let's say)

```
Person A = new Person(Apple);
Person B = new Person(Banana, Papaya);
Person C = new Person(Pineapple, Orange);
```

and a method in class Person `Fruit[] getFavouriteFruits(){}`

Using streams, I am trying to convert this into Map

Expected Output: Map of ((Apple, A), (Banana, B), (Papaya, B), (Pineapple, C), (Orange, C))

Not sure how to flatten the Array of Fruits into a stream

Answer (score 2):

I hope I don't have typos. The idea is to transform the `List<Person>` to a `Stream` of all the pairs of (`Person,Fruit`) and group them by `Fruit`.

```
Map<Fruit,List<Person>> map =
  List.of(A,B,C)
      .stream()
      .flatMap(p -> Arrays.stream(p.getFavouriteFruits())
                          .map(f -> new SimpleEntry<Person,Fruit>(p,f)))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                     Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                        Collectors.toList())));
```

`SimpleEntry` is `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

Comment: Or not swapping `<Person,Fruit>` to `<Fruit, List<Person>, one can create entries such as `new SimpleEntry<Fruit,Person>(f,p)` which might read easier.